# MGWT ScrollPanel is not scrollable?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, mgwt

I have the following ui binder structure using mgwt 1.2-Snapshot.

```
<mgwt:LayoutPanel>  

    <g:FlowPanel />

    <mgwt:LayoutPanel>

        <b:MyTouchPanel>
            <g:Label ></g:Label>
            <g:Label></g:Label>
        </b:MyTouchPanel>

    </mgwt:LayoutPanel>

    <b:MyTouchPanel >

        <mgwt:LayoutPanel ui:field="contentPanel">

            <b:MyTouchPanel>
            </b:MyTouchPanel>

            <mgwt:ScrollPanel ui:Field="panel2">    
                <b:MyTouchPanel ></b:MyTouchPanel >
            </mgwt:ScrollPanel>

        </mgwt:LayoutPanel>

    </b:MyTouchPanel>


</mgwt:LayoutPanel>
```

The previous one is working fine. I refresh the red marked schrollPanel each time the content changes. My problem is that the following is not working:

```
<mgwt:LayoutPanel>  

    <g:FlowPanel />

    <mgwt:LayoutPanel>

        <b:MyTouchPanel>
            <g:Label ></g:Label>
            <g:Label></g:Label>
        </b:MyTouchPanel>

    </mgwt:LayoutPanel>

    <b:MyTouchPanel >

        <mgwt:LayoutPanel ui:field="contentPanel">

            <b:MyTouchPanel>
            </b:MyTouchPanel>

            <mgwt:LayoutPanel>  
                <b:MyTouchPanel ui:Field="panel1"></b:MyTouchPanel>
                <mgwt:ScrollPanel ui:Field="panel2">    
                    <b:MyTouchPanel ></b:MyTouchPanel >
                    </mgwt:ScrollPanel>
            </mgwt:LayoutPanel> 

        </mgwt:LayoutPanel>

    </b:MyTouchPanel>


</mgwt:LayoutPanel>
```

When I wrap the scrollPanel in a LayoutPanel it is not scrollable anymore. I have to do it this way because The red marked pieces are from a new page which are rendered in the overall layout. Since ui binder does not allow more than one root element I have to wrap panel1 and pane2 (the ScrollPanel) in another Panel for which I choose the LayoutPanel.

**Is there a way to get the ScrollPanel (panel2) work correctly in my case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use a normal container like a `FlowPanel`, and put inside the boxes in an absolute position (*have you played with `css`?? Maybe is the best solution for your problem*).

Then, you have inside the `FlowPanel` your `ScrollPanel` and inside it you can introduce whatever you want.

If the `panel1` contains a lot of info, you can do it using `GQuery` manually, in that way GWT won't know that the `ScrollPanel` has more than one child (**but this is a tricky nasty solution** :D).

Hope it helps.